# To bind Values to Html Table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

In the below code i have a html table  with text box and dropdown list and i want to bind values from datset to html table.But it binds only 1 row but it has 15 records.Pls help me to do this.

**Asp.net Code :-**

```
 public string getWhileLoopData()
        {
            GetProduct();
            string htmlStr = "";
            MastersClient objIndent = new MastersClient();
            DataSet ds = objIndent.GetIndent(hidIndentID.Value);

            DataRow[] drIndentID = ds.Tables[0].Select("IndentID =" + hidIndentID.Value);

            for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                txtQty.Value = drIndentID[i]["RecommentedQuantity"].ToString();
                string Qty = txtQty.Value;
                string strProductID = drIndentID[i]["ProductID"].ToString();
                ddlProduct.Text = strProductID;
                txtDate.Text = drIndentID[i]["ProductRequiredDate"].ToString();
                string date = txtDate.Text;
               Response.Write( htmlStr += "<tr><td>" + Qty + "</td><td>" + strProductID + "</td><td>" + date + "</td></tr>");
            }


            return htmlStr;
        }
```

**Html Table :-**

```
  <table id="dataTable" width="350px" border="1" runat="server">
            <tr >
                <td><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="chk" runat="server"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="txt" id="txtQty" runat="server"/></td>
                <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProduct" runat="server"  Style="width: 100%; height:23px" ></asp:DropDownList>  


                </td>
               <td>
               <asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" Style="text-align: left" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event, false);"
                                                            onblur="DateValidation(this)" onkeyup="ValidateDate(this, event.keyCode)" onkeydown="return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)"
                                                            Height="20px" runat="server" Width="80px"> </asp:TextBox>


               </td>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Comment: This is clear that your controls(txtQty,txtData,..) will fill by the latest row in for loop and response.write does not add new row to your html table.

Comment: @aria so how can we add new rows and add values to it?

Comment: Now see the answer and write your comment there to complete.

Comment: You can use gridview and add template fields like textbox and dropdown list to gridview

Answer (score 0):

You can add new row to HTML table by `HtmlTableRow` , just for example do something like this:

```
        HtmlTableRow row ;
        HtmlTableCell cell;
        for (int i = 0; i < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            row = new HtmlTableRow();
            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(drIndentID[i]["RecommentedQuantity"].ToString()));
            row.Cells.Insert(0, cell);

            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(drIndentID[i]["ProductID"].ToString()));
            row.Cells.Insert(1, cell);

            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(drIndentID[i]["ProductRequiredDate"].ToString()));
            row.Cells.Insert(2, cell);
            dataTable.Rows.Insert(i, row);//If you want to add new rows after the exist tr use dataTable.Rows.Insert(i+1, row);
        }
```

Gridview is most powerful and useful control for sorting, paging, editing, delete, and formatting as well as you can working with dropdown, checkbox and textbox controls in GridView

See this below links:

[GridView Example1](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource14-Dropdown-checkbox-and-textbox-controls-in-aspnet-editable-Gridview.aspx)

[GridView Example2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972948.aspx)

[GridView Example3](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37207/Editable-Gridview-with-Textbox-CheckBox-Radio-Butt)

Comment: It is not binding along with controls textbox and dropdown

Comment: How do you want bind text boxes?

Comment: i have 2 textbox and dropdownlist the values should be bind textbox and dropdown in the table so can i edit

Comment: As I mentioned in that 'for' textboxes will filled by latest row and by the above snippet code records will add to HTML table programmatically, but to edit you must do something else or you can use GridView it is easy to use.